# Array contents disapearing

Tags: c, arrays, corruption

I'm trying to pass an array to a function and fill it with information. This code is from an exercise to lean the basic of bitwise operations in C, but the array "deck" is becomeing corrupted when it is parsed to the function "filldeck". Up to there it works as intended.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef unsigned char card;
typedef unsigned char pairs;

/* arrays for the names of things */
static char *suits[] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
static char *values[]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six",\
                    "Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack",\
                    "Queen","King"};
static char *colour[]= {"Black","Red"};

/* function prototypes */
void printcard(card c); /* Displays the value of a card*/

void printdeck(card deck[52]); /* prints an entire deck of cards*/

void filldeck(card deck[52]); /* Populates a deck of cards */

void shuffle(card deck[52]); /* Randomizes the order of cards */

int compareface(const void* c1,const void *c2); 
/* compares the face value of 2 cards, suitable to pass to qsort
as the fourth argument */

pairs findpairs(card *hand); /* finds any pairs in a hand */

int main()
{
    card deck[52],*deckp;
    card hands[5][5],handssorted[5][5];
    pairs numpairs[5],highest;
    int hand,cd,winner;

    srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

    /*populate and shuffle the deck */

    filldeck(deck);
    scanf("%*c*");
    printdeck(deck);
    scanf("%*c");
    shuffle(deck);
    printdeck(deck);
}
```

```
void filldeck(card deck[52])
{
    /* populate the deck here */
    int x = 0;
    //hearts
    for(int y = 64; y <=112;y += 4)
    {
        deck[0 + x] = y;
        x ++;
    }
    //diamonds
    for(int y = 1; y <=49;y += 4)
    {
        deck[0 + x] = y;
        x ++;
    }
    //clubs
    for(int y = 2; y <=50;y += 4)
    {
        deck[0 + x] = y;
        x ++;
    }
    //spades
    for(int y = 67; y <=115;y += 4)
    {
        deck[0 + x] = y;
        x ++;
    }
    printf("Deck filled");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: Why write `0 + x`? The result will always be `x`.

Comment: what do you mean with "corrupted"?

Comment: your `deck` is supposed to keep only 52 elements but your function goes beyond its size

Comment: @JKB Note the `y += 4` in the loops.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg oh..right it's my mistake.removed comment.Thanks to point out.

Comment: If you're doing what I think you are your deck-flll should be simply loaded with values from 0..51, then randomly shuffled. Suit and rank are computational. A card "suit" is `(deck[i] % 4)` returning a 0..3 value to index in your `suits[]` array for the text-name for suit. Likewise, the *rank* of a card (its numeric value) is `(deck[i] % 13)`, returning a value from 0..12 and once again, used to index `values[]` to obtain the text name for rank.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Good idea, why not make this into a full answer? There's one thing, though: You can't find the suit and rank with the remainders to the two dimensions, but with one integer division and one remainder to the _same_ dimension, for example the number of cards in a suit: `suit = deck[i] / 13` and `rank = deck[i] % 13`

Comment: To clarify, the problem is when the array is passed from main to the function, the contents disappears. The function is working as intended, but its only assigning 1 value to the array as the array changes to only have 1 value in it.

Comment: @MOehm I understand. there is a reason I didn't lay it out like that. the suits don't have to be sequentially laid out. Yes, as i have it the sequential deck is Two of spades, three of clubs, four of diamonds, etc.., but each card still ultimately has singular representation. The bonus is adding decks. you can throw N*52 cards into the scheme i laid out for an N-deck shoe, and all the math still just works. I use the scheme often because of that reason.

Comment: @MOehm and the reason i don't make it an answer is because its an alternate config, not really solving the OP's bit twiddling problem. Otherwise i would.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Okay, I didn't see that. It works, but just because the number of ranks is coprime to the number of suits. It wouldn't work with a 32-card deck of 8 ranks and 4 suits (as is customary where I come from). I don't really see the advantage of your approach here and I'd prefer a deck where the unshuffled "factory" order consists of blocks of suits. Adding more decks is easily catered for.

Comment: @MOehm Ah... man you have *big* decks =P (lookout, here come the censors). you're correct. I would totally use your model given that, to be sure.

Comment: Fix the weird logic used to fill the deck. In the worst case, do a loop over the number of the card and compute the suit and value from its position. As written, it is just too hard to understand (and thus easy to write wrong). It isn't that this is exactly performance critical... Are you *sure*"your `printdeck()` is working right? If it is a similar rat's nest...

Answer (score 0):

The function `filldeck()` increments `x` beyond 51 and uses it to index `deck[52]`. That way, you go beyond array boundaries and invoke **undefined behavior**.